# Are there any limits to the amount of text one can 'grab' with window.getSelection or document.selection.createRange()?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, getselection

I can't seem to find this info anywhere?

Do `window.getSelection()` or `document.selection.createRange()` hold a set # of characters or can they hold an infinite/huge #?

I am working on a bookmarklet and want to know if I need to restrict the amount of text one copies.

Comment: If you had enough selectable text to cause a problem, I don't see the browser being able to render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit other than the normal practical limits in the size of a web page.